# DELETE function is deleting the logo, but I don't want it to delete the logo

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure, graphical-logo

I have a GUI in Matlab, where I have a DELETE BUTTON, after I click on it, it as well deletes the logo in it.

The code for the DELETE function:

```
clc

figure('Name', 'Vektorkardiogram');
%Return handle to figure named 'Vectorcardiogram'.
h = findobj('Name', 'Vektorkardiogram');
close(h);


figure('Name', 'Roviny');
%Return handle to figure named 'Vectorcardiogram'.
r = findobj('Name', 'Roviny');
close(r);


figure('Name', 'P vlna');
%Return handle to figure named 'Vectorcardiogram'.
p = findobj('Name', 'P vlna');
close(p);


figure('Name', 'QRS komplex');
%Return handle to figure named 'Vectorcardiogram'.
q = findobj('Name', 'QRS komplex');
close(q);


figure('Name', 'T vlna');
%Return handle to figure named 'Vectorcardiogram'.
t = findobj('Name', 'T vlna');
close(t);

arrayfun(@cla,findall(0,'type','axes'));
delete(findall(findall(gcf,'Type','axe'),'Type','text'));
```

The code for uploading the logo (I have made a GUI in Matlab using the guide command, so this code below is inserted inside the GUI code):

```
logo4 = imread('logo4.png','BackgroundColor',[1 1 1]);
imshow(logo4)
```

Pusghing the DELETE BUTTON, I just want to close certain figure windwos, not to delete the logo. Could you please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are clearing all `axes` using `cla` which includes the logo that you don't want to delete.

```
arrayfun(@cla,findall(0,'type','axes'));
```

Instead of clearing everything, it's better to delete and clear *specific* objects.

```
cla(handles.axes10)
cla(handles.axes11)
```

Alternately, if you keep the handle to the `image` object, you can ignore the axes that contains it when clearing axes

```
himg = imshow(data);

allaxes = findall(0, 'type', 'axes');
allaxes = allaxes(~ismember(allaxes, ancestor(himg, 'axes')));

cla(allaxes)
```

Also, you shouldn't ever do `findall(0, ...` in your GUI because if I open a figure before opening my GUI you will alter the state of my *other* figure. Instead, use `findall(gcbf, ...` which will only alter children of your own GUI. Either that, or use a `'Tag'` specific to your GUI and then use `findall` to filter for that specific tag.

```
figure('Tag', 'mygui')

findall(0, 'Tag', 'mygui')
```

**Update**

You should use `findall` combined with the `'Name'` parameter to figure out which of your figures actually exists

```
figs = findall(0, 'Name', 'Vektorkardiogram', ...
               '-or', 'Name', 'Roviny', ...
               '-or', 'Name', 'P vlna', ...
               '-or', 'Name', 'QRS komplex', ...
               '-or', 'Name', 'T vlna');
delete(figs);
```

And for clearing the `axes`, you can ensure that they exist

```
ax = findall(0, 'tag', 'axes10', '-or', 'tag', 'axes11', '-or', 'tag', 'axes12');     
cla(ax)
```

Comment: I will try it out.

Comment: I have tried this code, but still didn't work, it writes specified windows doesn't exist:


    `figure('Tag', 'Vektorkardiogram')`
    `close('Vektorkardiogram')`

Not always must all of the windows exist.

Comment: Why are you calling `close('Vektorkardiogram')`? That doesn't match anything that I wrote...

Comment: The `close('Vektorkardiogram')` is a name one of 6 possible figure windows.

Comment: Vektorkardiogram, P vlna, QRS komplex, T vlna, Roviny: These are five names of 5 figures which may and may not be visualized, these I need to close, and in axes10,11 an 12 I load the data. So these things I need to delete.

Comment: @john.steak So you need to check if it exists first...See the update

Comment: It closes all the figure windows as I needed! Thank you!
I was trying first to use this:

`if exist('Vektorkardiogram')`
`close('Vektorkardiogram')`
`end`

But your code works perfectly!
How do I as well specify, that I want to clear the axes10, axes11 and axes12?

Comment: @john.steak I had it in there but didn't have the check. I've added in the check now

Comment: It writes:

`Undefined variable "handles" or class "handles.axes10".`

Where can I define it?

Comment: @john.steak Is this not a callback of your GUI?

Comment: In the GUI I have these axes where I plot data: axes10, axes11 and axes12 (these are their names). I have used the `guide` command to create the GUI.

Comment: @john.steak Yes I realize that. Is the delete function not a callback? All callbacks receive a `handles` input by default

Comment: For the delete function I have created a button named `DELETE` and inside this this button I refer to the `clear_and_delete` function. Inside the `clear_and_delete` function I have the code for deleting.

Comment: @john.steak Why not just put the contents of `clear_and_delete` inside of the callback?

Comment: @john.steak Regardless, I've updated with a solution that will work by using the `'Tag'` property

Comment: I have tried both solutions, either one doesn't work. 
It cleares/deletes only the axes12, for both solutions.

Comment: @john.steak Did you look at *only* the code in my update? That definitely will not delete axes12